# Bash append line to lastline if case matches

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I got an Input like this:

```
ha  lo 
ha
ha  lo
ha
ha
ha  lo
```

How can i append the line to the last line if it doesn't contain the string "lo" in the second row. It should look like this afterwards

```
haha
hahaha
ha
```

I think this one is quite tricky. Would be nice to be able to do it with sed or awk.

Comment: Are all those "ha" really the same?

Comment: no. in real they are iscsi-disks whose names got sliced by an bad CLI: xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-dis read-write offline     0            
  k1-2012-09-19-11:12:24.21                                     
  7147                                                          
aaaa-bbbb-disk1-2012-09- read-write online      0            
  19-11:12:24.217142

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
    $2 == "lo" {if (line) print line; line = ""} 
    {line = line $1} 
    END {print line}
' filename
```

This is a bit simpler, but you get a leading blank line

```
awk '$2 == "lo" {print ""} {printf("%s", $1)} END {print ""}'
```

Comment: +1 for the 1st method. Also, `printf("%s", $1)` could be simply `printf $1` :-)

Comment: @steve: That won't work if `$1` happens to contain anything that looks like a format specifier. That's why you should always use one explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it with GNU sed:

*parse.sed*

```sed
/ +lo/! H          # Append to HS if / +lo/ doesn't match
/ +lo/ {           # If it does match
  s/ *lo//         # remove it
  x                # put the rest in HS and contents of HS in PS
  s/\n//g          # Remove all newlines from PS
  /./! t end       # If PS empty jump to end
  p                # otherwise print
  s/.*//           # and empty it
}

$ {                # If last line
  x                # swap PS/HS
  s/\n//g          # remove newlines
  p                # and print PS
}
: end
```

Run with:

```
sed -nr -f parse.sed < infile
```

Output:

```
haha
hahaha
ha
```

Comment: thanks for the explanations thor. it gives me an great idea how to use sed properly.

Comment: @Thor, this is a great answer, but also shows how ugly sed can get.. +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

where file.txt contains above entries

```
 i=0;IFS=$'\n'; for line in `cat file.txt`; do ((i++)); if [[ [$line =~ lo ]]; then if [ $i -eq 1 ];then ha=$(echo "$line"|awk '{print $1}'); echo -n $ha; else echo; ha=$(echo "$line"|awk '{print $1}'); echo -n  $ha; fi else echo  -n "$line"; fi done; echo
```

haha
hahaha
ha